# Sorting a dictionary with values as tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary as follows and I want to sort this based on the last element of the tuple in a non-increasing manner. However, if two or more of the last elements are the same, then they should be sorted based on the second element.

```
    capacity= {
    'one': (57000, 3100, 0.12903225806451613),
 'two': (52911, 2400, 0.125),
 'three': (48200, 2400, 0.125),
 'four': (48200, 2480, 0.125),
 'five': (11464, 1200, 0.20833333333333334),
 'six': (44000, 1172, 0.21331058020477817),
 'seven': (42000, 1172, 0.21331058020477817)}
```

After sorting by the third element of the tuple I get the following results.

```
sorted_capacity={k: (v1,v2,v3) for k, (v1,v2,v3) in sorted(capacity.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][2],reverse=True)}



sorted_capacity

{'six': (44000, 1172, 0.21331058020477817),
 'seven': (42000, 1172, 0.21331058020477817),
 'five': (11464, 1200, 0.20833333333333334),
 'one': (57000, 3100, 0.12903225806451613),
 'two': (52911, 2400, 0.125),
 'three': (48200, 2400, 0.125),
 'four': (48200, 2480, 0.125)}
```

However, as I mentioned before, I need to have `'four': (48200, 2480, 0.125)}` before `'two': (52911, 2400, 0.125), because 2480 is higher than 2400`. Basically my output should be like this:

```
sorted_capacity

    {'six': (44000, 1172, 0.21331058020477817),
     'seven': (42000, 1172, 0.21331058020477817),
     'five': (11464, 1200, 0.20833333333333334),
     'one': (57000, 3100, 0.12903225806451613),
     'four': (48200, 2480, 0.125),
     'two': (52911, 2400, 0.125),
     'three': (48200, 2400, 0.125)
     }
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
key = lambda x: (x[1][-1], x[1][1])
```

This compares tuples of the last and second elements in each tuple. Since tuples are ordered lexicographically, this produces the ordering you want.

Comment: This is great. Thank you!  I just realized that I need to sort it by the non-decreasing order of the third element and by the non-increasing order of the second element. Any hint on this if you can?

Comment: I just figured this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the key function, you can reverse the tuples to compare:

```
>>> dict(sorted(capacity.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][::-1], reverse=True))
{'six': (44000, 1172, 0.21331058020477817),
 'seven': (42000, 1172, 0.21331058020477817),
 'five': (11464, 1200, 0.20833333333333334),
 'one': (57000, 3100, 0.12903225806451613),
 'four': (48200, 2480, 0.125),
 'two': (52911, 2400, 0.125),
 'three': (48200, 2400, 0.125)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code with the issue fixed:

```
from pprint import pprint

capacity = {
    'one': (57000, 3100, 0.12903225806451613),
    'two': (52911, 2400, 0.125),
    'three': (48200, 2400, 0.125),
    'four': (48200, 2480, 0.125),
    'five': (11464, 1200, 0.20833333333333334),
    'six': (44000, 1172, 0.21331058020477817),
    'seven': (42000, 1172, 0.21331058020477817)}

sorted_capacity = {
    k: (v1, v2, v3)
    for k, (v1, v2, v3) in sorted(capacity.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1][2], x[1][1]), reverse=True)
}

pprint(sorted_capacity, sort_dicts=False)  # don't want pprint to sort again
```

This just adds the middle column to the sorting `key`. If you want the first column to be used when the second is also identical, you could also just reverse the tuple:

```
key=lambda x: tuple(reversed(x[1]))
```

Or:

```
key=lambda x: x[1][::-1]
```